# java unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

This question has been asked multiple times.

The answers are always "add the certificate to the truststore".

I have to work via a weird proxy server, which always sends *different* self-signed certificates.
Hence adding to truststore is not practical.

The only option is to disable SSL certificate validation.
I have this code, but it does not help :(
Any suggestion(s)?

(BTW, I don't care about security, we use this code in-house for testing)

```
@Slf4j
public class TrustAllX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @SneakyThrows({ KeyManagementException.class,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException.class })
    public static void disableSslCertificateValidation() {
        log.debug("turning off SSL certificate validation");
        val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null,
            new TrustManager[] { new TrustAllX509TrustManager() },
            new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultHostnameVerifier((string, ssls) -> true);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(
        final java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs,
        final String authType) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
        final java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs,
        final String authType) {
        // nothing to do here
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a custom implementation of the X509TrustManager. I had a similar issue as what you had and resolved it by using a different kind of base TrustManager.

So what I did was instead of implementing `X509TrustManager` I extended my custom trustmanager with `X509ExtendedTrustmanager`. See here for an example: [UnsafeX509ExtendedTrustManager](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart/blob/master/sslcontext-kickstart/src/main/java/nl/altindag/ssl/trustmanager/UnsafeX509ExtendedTrustManager.java)

I discovered that java is wrapping a TrustManager into a custom TrustManager of the type `X509ExtendedTrustmanager` which does not disable all the checks like you did in your snippet if it is an instance of `X509TrustManager`. So using a custom TrustManager of the type `X509ExtendedTrustmanager` should do the trick I think. Can you try and share your results?

Comment: It appears the Java still does not have a standard way for HTTP communication, and each library should be configured a bit different. For JAX-RS client, a specific SSLContext must be set while configuring the client. There are other HTTP/REST clients out there, and perhaps each has its own unique way. Currently I am stuck with AmazonHttpClient -- opened an issue at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2603

Comment: Thanks for sharing the issue link, looking at the stackstrace you shared on github I am pretty sure using the X509ExtendedTrustmanager instead of X509TrustManager should do the trick. Where you able to try that? I can share some example code snippets